# Insert dynamic class assignment to a Rails link_to tag

Tags: ruby, code-injection, link-to, rails7

I am trying to add a dynamic class to a `link_to` in Rails 7.  I have the following code, but it's not inserting the appropriate content based on the `request.env["PATH_INFO"]`...

```
<ul>
        <% %w[blog headlines network].each do |nav_link| %>
        <%= added_class = request.env["PATH_INFO"] == nav_link ? "nav_current" : nil %>
          <li class="btn"><%= link_to "#{nav_link}".capitalize, "/#{nav_link}", id: "nav_main", class: "btn btn_nav #{added_class}" %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

However, the resulting HTML is:

```
      <ul>
          <li class="btn"><a id="nav_main" class="btn btn_nav " href="/blog">Bog</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a id="nav_main" class="btn btn_nav " href="/headlines">Headlines</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a id="nav_main" class="btn btn_nav " href="/network">Network</a></li>
      </ul>
```

As you can see, the `added_class` doesn't get inserted.  Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`link_to_unless_current`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current) and the other `URLHelper' methods.` because `link_to_unless_current` exists for exactly your use case...

Comment: @spickerman - Good point.  This is exactly what this use case needs.  It is easy to assign a class to this helper method.  +1 for teaching!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.env['PATH_INFO']` contains a leading `/` (at least on Rails 7; and IIRC on previous versions as well)

That means that if you are visiting `localhost:3000/blog`, `request.env['PATH_INFO']` is `/blog`, not `blog`.

The following code should fix it:

```
<ul>
  <% %w[blog headlines network].each do |nav_link| %>
    <% added_class = request.env["PATH_INFO"] == "/#{nav_link}" ? "nav_current" : nil %>
    <li class="btn"><%= link_to "#{nav_link}".capitalize, "/#{nav_link}", id: "nav_main", class: "btn btn_nav #{added_class}" %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Thanks for your contribution.  I would point out the `nil` in your code that I had in the beginning.  `Nil` returns erroneously.  You need to insert `""` instead.

Comment: I don't think that is needed. Even with `nil`, it works for me. I just see extra space in the class attribute.

Comment: @Ankit the other approach that would work would be to use the Rails helpers`controller_name` or `controller_path`, which for instance, would return `blog` and you would not have to worry about matching with the `/`. Just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the following code does what I wanted it to.  It injects a custom class into the link tag so that I can track the current button and style it differently... :

```
      <ul>
        <% %w[blog headlines network].each do |nav_link| %>
        <% add_class = request.env['PATH_INFO'] == "/#{nav_link}" ? "nav_current" : "" %>
          <li class="btn"><%= link_to "#{nav_link}".capitalize, "/#{nav_link}", id: "nav_main", class: "btn btn_nav #{add_class}" %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

No Javascript necessary.